# How to make div fixed such that scrolling text does not overpass it?

Tags: html, css

I am making a nav bar which is inside a div with display:fixed.
But i text keeps on scrolling over nav bar.
How to solve my problem such that text scrolls bypassing the div.

Comment: can u show your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following on your div and the div containing your text:**

`z-index: anyvalue;`

> The higher the value the more items it will overlap and items with lower
>   value will go beneath the ones with higher.